# I’m trying to manipulate the harmonics of a square wave, and my circuit is not working

Tags: active-filter, harmonics

I am trying to build a circuit that can boost or cut multiple harmonics of a square wave. I am trying to use a graphic equalizer gyrator circuit. I have had very little luck with this. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

[image]

Here is my circuit. It is a square wave generator feeding a schmitt trigger feeding a single band of a gyrator graphic equalizer. It will work in a limited capacity for this single band, but this equalizer circuit does not seem suited to what I’m trying to do. The fundamental frequency is 289.363Hz, and I am trying to create a circuit that can selectively boost the first six harmonics.

Comment: I suggest that you post your schematic, tell us what you expected and what you got.

Comment: Sorry, I’m a little new to all this. Do I post it to this comment, or do I post It under “answer your question?”

Comment: You edit your question to include the missing details. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Hi! When you say you want to manipulate select harmonics, about how many are we talking? How much amplification does "boost" imply, how much attenuation "cut"? (Please state a number, not just "as much as possible") what's the highest harmonic that you care about at all? (This is also answerable by "what's the overall bandwidth of the system") generally, I wonder why you're taking this approach and not doing something way simpler, so maybe an explanation of the purpose of this circuit's intended output would be helpful!

Comment: I want to manipulate the first six harmonics. The first harmonic should be 75% of the magnitude of the fundamental (5Vp). The next magnitude should be 50% of the fundamental. Then 14% (third) 50% (4th) 12% (5th) and 17% (6th harmonic). I don’t care about anything above the 6th harmonic (3.757k). If there’s a much simpler way to do this, then I would be perfectly happy to implement that instead. Thanks.

Comment: So your system has less than 5 kHz overall bandwidth - this suggests that if you build it as digital system, it would be very easy to implement accurately with little effort. I'll assume you already know what the waveform will look like by having programmed a sum of cosines with your amplitudes on a PC; so, sample these cosines at a sampling rate that your sound card supports, and play their sum as sound. Great prototype at zero cost! If you then still need to shrink this down: a cheap DAC and a microcontroller can calculate and synthesize the same!

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not an option for me. I have to do this with analog circuits.

Comment: @WTFisChris If your waveform is square, it will only have odd harmonics, so it's pointless to talk about the amplitude of the even ones. Which means you're left with 75%@1, 14%@3, 12%/5, and that's it. And since a unity square wave is made of 4/pi*sin(kx)/k terms, multiplying these with your coefficients gives you [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDMFg.png) (only 3 terms). Also, your "EQ" is not a clear bandpass, you'll need a [proper circuit](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/), since a true bandpass has zero phase delay at f0.

Comment: So I should have a semi-sinusoid output? The circuit I just build is a passive graphic equalizer. It boosts the frequencies that I needed it to, but the output looks nothing like a sinusoid.

Comment: "I have to do this with analog circuits" ....why?

Comment: That is certainly a good question. Consider it a limitation of the project. There are probably plenty of better ways. The output waveform is supposed to mimic the sound of a clarinet.